# Как получить временную метку(timestamp) из набора байт

Tags: python, timestamp

Есть временная метка размером 8 байт, полученная путем чтения данных из файла. Необходимо ее преобразовать в datetime.

```
ts = b'\x13\x88\x5B\xFF\xF3\x91\x34\x16'
```

Что пробовал и не подошло:

- преобразование метки в int и передача в fromtimestamp(и utcfromtimestamp)

```
    ts = b'\x13\x88\x5B\xFF\xF3\x91\x34\x16'
    int_ts = int.from_bytes(ts, byteorder='little')
    a = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int_ts)
```

- библиотека struct

  ````
  recoverbinstamp = struct.unpack('<L', ts)[0]
  recovernow = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(recoverbinstamp)```
  ````

Как я понял, временная метка хранит в себе количество секунд и миллисекунд. Может их как-то вручную можно извлечь или преобразовать.

Answer (score 5):

```
import struct
byte_range = b'\x13\x88\x5B\xFF\xF3\x91\x34\x16'
a = struct.unpack_from('!HBBBBB', byte_range)
print(a)
>>> (5000, 91, 255, 243, 145, 52)

byte_range = b'\x07\xe3\n\n\x04\n\x0f\x00\x00\x00<\x00'
>>> (2019, 10, 10, 4, 10, 15)
```

очень странная у вас временная метка

Форма кортежа `datetime` (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, ...).

Глядя на размер каждого символа формата и зная, насколько велика каждая часть datetime, вы можете выяснить, какой символ формата вам нужен.

- `B` представляет собой беззнаковый символ, 1 байт, диапазон значений: от 0 до 255
- `H` представляет собой короткий беззнаковый 2 байта, диапазон значений: от 0 до 65535
  Как видите, `B` слишком мал для хранения значения года, поэтому вам нужен `H`.

Теперь вы знаете, что время состоит из 3 чисел, диапазон значений которых составляет от 0 до 60, таким образом, `B` это то, что вам нужно для всех из них, заканчивая форматом `!HBBBBB`.

Comment: я видел подобную конструкцию - '!HBBBBB', но не совсем понял как ее использовать для timestamp. как я понял, что тут описывается порядок чтения байт? unsigned short, потом идут unsigned char. Можете объяснить логику использования? Метка формировал не я, а в чем странность?

Comment: отредактировал ответ

Comment: Я не совсем понял еще тему с временными метками, но есть метки которые занимают 8 байт, есть которые 11. В них хранится какая-то временная зона и т.д. Да, представленный пример странен, но если открыть hexworkshop и выделить данные байты, он преобразует их в time_t = 20:45:51 20.05.1980. Вопрос как он это делает, и как это сделать в python.

Comment: Еще одна разница в том, что это uniх timestamp - т.е. количество секунд с 01.01.1970, как я понял в python timestamp хранит просто время в байтовом представлении.

Answer (score 1):

Я немного подразобрался и отвечу сам. Для начала рассмотрим [определение](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) временной метки:
unix timestamp - это количество СЕКУНД прошедших с 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970(Unix epoch).
В моем же случае временная метка указана в наносекундах, еще есть в микросекундах и т.д.

Для преобразования из timestamp в дату можно использовать методы `datetime.utcfromtimestamp` и `datetime.fromtimestamp`. Если же временная метка представлена в наносекундах, то придется писать свою функцию, например вот [эту](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15650126/10230655).

В представленном ответе от Violet рассматривается преобразование из типа datetime.